# Paste rows from one sheet to another with paste link option

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

I am able to paste the rows from one worksheet to another using:

```
sourceSheet.UsedRange.Copy();

destinationSheet.UsedRange.PasteSpecial(
    Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, 
    Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
```

But i also want that any changes made to the cells in source sheet should be reflected in destination sheet.
(paste link option in excel)
How to do this in c#?